# How to extract Form fields using getElementBy without having any of the attributes present in the <input> tag

Tags: html, angularjs, vba, getelementsbyname

I am trying to use the ie.document.getElementById method in a VBA script to access html form elements such as Username and Password fields. This method works on an html page, but does not on an angularJS page. I am trying to figure out what needs to be changed to work with the angularJS page.

from a simple html login page, I can use this code and it works perfectly. I am able to assign the username and password values from a previous variable.

```
---------------------VBA code-----------------------
    set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    With ie
     .Visible = True
     .navigate "https://signin.lexisnexis.com"
    DoEvents
     Loop
       Set user = ie.document.getElementById("userid")
          user.Value = Username
       Set pw = ie.document.getElementById("password")
          pw.Value = Password
---------------------------------------------------
```

The page for the above code has this as the `<input>` tag:

```
<label for="userid" style="padding-top:20px;"> 
   ID <span class="error">Please enter a valid ID.</span>
   <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" class="major"
          onblur="this.value=trim(this.value)">
   <span class="error icon la-Warning"></span>
</label>
```

But I am trying to do the exact same thing but on a login page which is built using angularJS:
[image: helper image]

Comment: You should not be accessing DOM elements directly when using angular, but rather the underlying `model` to which your controls are bound to.

Comment: The `ng-model` directive listens for a `'change'` event before updating scope with a new `input.value`.

Comment: please supply an example angularjs page that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: Yes makes sense so in this case, it will be either the model='login.user', but how do I access the underlying model? Please pardon my lack of knowledge regarding angular. Could you please share some kind of an example code that might demonstrate how the model can be accessed instead of the DOM element?

Comment: @QHarr, I can try to send a sceencap of the entire page but will be difficult to provide more details as this page/portal is on a client network and I can't bring it over to my laptop to share here.

Comment: Does your code populate the input box initially?

Comment: The code is not able to even read/access the login and password form fields. Populating the fields is the goal. If we are able to extract the form fields, we can then assign a predefined username/password and then populate the fields and click the enter button to login. But the first step is to access those form fields - which is where I am stuck

Comment: Did you try ie.document.querySelector("[label*='User Name'] input").value = "xyz"

Comment: I get this error message: Method 'querySelector' of object 'JScriptTypeInfo' failed